# Configure a directory scanner on an inbound channel with Spring Integration Java DSL on Spring Integration 5

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

So Spring Integration 5 introduced the concept of a directory scanner for inbound channels and I'm keen to use this with my ftp channel.

However I'm not sure how to configure it with Java DSL. The [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.1.x/reference/html/#ftp-inbound) say I can set the scanner on the scanner inbound-channel-adapter in xml. However, I'm using [Spring Integration DSL via IntegrationFlow](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.1.x/reference/html/#configuring-with-the-java-dsl-11) and it appears that I have no way of setting this directory scanner when taking this approach...

Is this true? Is there a way I can set the directory scanner with IntegrationFlow. I know I can move to using a more formal Java Config approach but I'd prefer not to as that would be a lot of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like we have just missed to add a `scanner` option to the DSL.

However here is a simple workaround for you:

```
    FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource ftpSource =
            Ftp.inboundAdapter(sessionFactory())
                    .regexFilter(".*\\.txt$")
                    .get();
    ftpSource.setScanner(...);
    IntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows.from(ftpSource,
```

So, what you need is to extract a target object from the DSL Spec and call its setter directly.

Feel free to contribute the `.scanner()` option into the `RemoteFileInboundChannelAdapterSpec` back to the Framework!